# Azure data Factory and power shell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMpkz.png)
Hi Stack team,
actually i plan to migrate my SQL server2012 databases to Azure data warehouse with Azure data factory approach...
But problems are,
1) my database size is 4.5 TB
2)in this approach there are 3 methods. those method details i mentioned in the attached image.. my problem is i planed to 3rd method for migrate(3.Using Azure Data Factory and PowerShell (entire database - ADF))

```
       so please tell me links related above method and its possible for migration or not. if its possiable send me how to do...
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Flagged for closure.

Answer (score 0):

Please refers to the link below, there's an UX solution in Azure Data Factory which are just target for migration from SQL Server to Azure SQL Datawarehouse. It's a wizard based UX which are very easy to follow. It will automatically create tables in Azure SQL Datawarehouse and migrate the data using polybase, which is the most efficient way to load data into SQLDW.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-with-data-factory